# Interpreting specific bits in Numpy-Array

Tags: python, numpy, bit

I am trying to interpret HDF-files or more precisely the Rasterbands inside the files. There is a Band that is used for Quality Assessment which represents Bit-Information as corresponding integers (e.g. 01000000 as 64).

Depending on specific bits I want to get a count, e.g. how many of the Pixels are 1 on bit position 5. If they are taken into account by a previous count, the should not get count again. Right now I am changing the entries in each cell depending on a priority-list by myself. This takes ages and I am really sure that there are faster ways since I have never worked with bits before.

Here is my code:

```
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np
QA_Band = gdal.Open(hdf.GetSubDatasets()[B][0],gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
QA = QA_Band.ReadAsArray()

# Calculate Bit-Representation of QA-Band
bin_vec = np.vectorize(np.binary_repr)
QAB = bin_vec(QA, width = 8)

# Filter by Bit-Values
QAB = np.where(QAB == '11111111', "OutOfSwath", QAB)

for i in range(QAB.shape[0]):
    for j in range(QAB.shape[1]):
        if QAB[i,j][6] == '1':
            QAB[i,j] = "Cloud"
            Cloud = (QAB == "Cloud").sum()
        elif QAB[i,j][4] == '1':
            QAB[i,j] = "Cloud Shadow"      
            Shadow = (QAB == "Cloud Shadow").sum()
        elif QAB[i,j][5] == '1':
            QAB[i,j] = "Adjacent Cloud"
            AC = (QAB == "Adjacent Cloud").sum()

        elif QAB[i,j][7] == '1':
            QAB[i,j] = "Cirrus"
            Cirrus = (QAB == "Cirrus").sum()

        elif QAB[i,j][3] == '1':
            QAB[i,j] = "Snow/Ice"
            SnowC = (QAB == "Snow/Ice").sum()
        elif QAB[i,j][2] == '1':
            QAB[i,j] = "Water"
            WaterC = (QAB == "Water").sum()

        elif QAB[i,j][0:1] == '11':
            QAB[i,j] = "High Aerosol"        
        elif QAB[i,j][0:1] == '10':
            QAB[i,j] = "Avrg. Aerosol"        
        elif QAB[i,j][0:1] == '01':
            QAB[i,j] = "Low Aerosol"
        elif QAB[i,j][0:1] == '00':
            QAB[i,j] = "Aerosol Climatology"
```

This will lead to an array of strings representing the different things, but takes ages as said before.

Any help in how to access the Bit-Representation would be helpful :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use numpy function [unpackbits](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.unpackbits.html) to handle bits. With numpy we prefer to use numpy methods and functions instead of python for loop - generally it is faster. So you can unpack each number to the third axis and then conditions like `QAB[i, j][5] == '1'` turn to `result[bits[5]]`. I reverse the order of you elif clauses as if you `QAB[i, j][6] == '1'` then it set it to `"Cloud"` and never run over clauses so this case should be last to rewrite overs if we run each condition. Also your last cases like `QAB[i,j][0:1] == '11'` never triggered as left hand side always has the length 1. So I rewrite with the consumption that you mean `QAB[i,j][0:2] == ...`.

```
"""
>>> print(bits)
[[[False False False]
  [False False  True]]
<BLANKLINE>
 [[False False False]
  [False False  True]]
<BLANKLINE>
 [[False False False]
  [False False  True]]
<BLANKLINE>
 [[False False False]
  [False False  True]]
<BLANKLINE>
 [[False False False]
  [False  True  True]]
<BLANKLINE>
 [[False False False]
  [False False  True]]
<BLANKLINE>
 [[False  True  True]
  [ True False  True]]
<BLANKLINE>
 [[ True False  True]
  [ True  True  True]]]
>>> print(result)
[['Cirrus' 'Cloud' 'Cloud']
 ['Cloud' 'Cloud Shadow' 'OutOfSwath']]
>>> Cloud
3
"""
import numpy as np
QA = [[1, 2, 3], [3, 9, 255]]

bits = np.unpackbits(np.array(QA, dtype=np.uint8, ndmin=3), axis=0).astype(bool)
result = np.array([[""] * bits.shape[2] for _ in range(bits.shape[1])], dtype=object)
result[~bits[0] & ~bits[1]] = "Aerosol Climatology"
result[~bits[0] & bits[1]] = "Low Aerosol"
result[bits[0] & ~bits[1]] = "Avrg. Aerosol"
result[bits[0] & bits[1]] = "High Aerosol"
result[bits[2]] = "Water"
result[bits[3]] = "Snow/Ice"
result[bits[7]] = "Cirrus"
result[bits[5]] = "Adjacent Cloud"
result[bits[4]] = "Cloud Shadow"
result[bits[6]] = "Cloud"
result[bits.all(axis=0)] = "OutOfSwath"
Cloud = (result == "Cloud").sum()
Shadow = (result == "Cloud Shadow").sum()
AC = (result == "Adjacent Cloud").sum()
Cirrus = (result == "Cirrus").sum()
SnowC = (result == "Snow/Ice").sum()
WaterC = (result == "Water").sum()
```

Answer (score 1):

The logic of your program actually maps precisely onto `numpy.select` which element-wise selects from a list of arrays according to a list of condition (boolean) arrays, first match wins. So you could compactly write something like

```
conditions = QAB&(128>>np.arange(8))[:,None,None]
values = ["OutOfSwath","Cloud","Cloud Shadow","Adjacent Cloud","Cirrus","Snow/Ice",
          "Water","High Aerosol","Avrg. Aerosol","Low Aerosol","Aerosol Climatology"]

np.select([QAB==255,*conditions[[6,4,5,7,3,2]],*(QAB==np.arange(0,256,64)[::-1,None,None])],values)
```

Comment: I tried you solution but get an error: TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Comment: @Felix What type is your (original) `QAB`? It should be an intenger type. Could you please share the output of `QAB.dtype`?

Comment: QA is "Array of uint8", QAB was the result of bin_vec = np.vectorize(np.binary_repr)
QAB = bin_vec(QA, width = 8), it is an "array of str256".
I used ur code-snippet on QAB, but maybe should have used it on QA instead if I interpret ur answer right.

Comment: @Felix or rather I shouöld have spotted the difference between `QA` and `QAB`. Anyways, does it work with `QA`?

Comment: We had holiday yesterday and i was not in office today to test it. I will check on monday and update you :)

Comment: I got the error    'invalid entry {} in condlist: should be boolean ndarray'.format(i))

TypeError: invalid entry 1 in condlist: should be boolean ndarray

As of now the other solution here works, so you do not have to worry to much :/